# How to get the residual variance-covariance matrix in glmmTMB?

Tags: r, lme4, glmmtmb

This question is the twin of the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650548/get-residual-variance-covariance-matrix-in-lme4/45655597#45655597) for lme4. Given that glmmTMB allows users to specify residual correlation structures more flexibly than lme4, it would be nice to visualize the residual variance covariance matrix. How can we do so?

The problem I am having is extracting the "Lambda" in the model fitting process that runs behind the scenes for glmmTMB.

Provided in the linked question is the code to do so in lme4:

```
rescov <- function(model, data) {
  var.d <- crossprod(getME(model,"Lambdat"))
  Zt <- getME(model,"Zt")
  vr <- sigma(model)^2
  var.b <- vr*(t(Zt) %*% var.d %*% Zt)
  sI <- vr * Diagonal(nrow(data))
  var.y <- var.b + sI
  invisible(var.y)
}
```

I would like to translate this to work on a glmmTMB model. The [getME](https://rdrr.io/cran/glmmTMB/man/getME.glmmTMB.html) for glmmTMB allows us to reuse the above code to get the 'Z' (and thus 'Zt') and 'sigma' components, but it does not allow us to extract the needed relative covariance factor as it is defined in lme4. That is, `getME(model, "Lambdat")` does not work for a glmmTMB model as "Lambdat" is not an allowable argument for the glmmTMB model.

Exploring the glmmTMB getME I have not found a way to do this. I can generally see where this "Lambda" is defined in the lme4 package write-up [at page 3 equation 4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf) but the inner-workings of glmmTMB are above me and I have not found a way to extract a "Lambda" for such a model.

The code below sets up up a model using lme4 and glmmTMB, shows how we can apply the above function on an lmerMod object, but not on an glmmTMB object.

```
library(lme4)
library(glmmTMB)
data("Pastes")
lme.fit <- lmer(strength ~ (1|batch/cask), data=Pastes)
image(rescov(lme.fit, Pastes))
glmm.fit <- glmmTMB(strength ~ (1|batch/cask), data=Pastes)
image(rescov(glmm.fit, Pastes))
```

Comment: The problem is that `glmmTMB` doesn't ever construct the `Lambda` matrix explicitly; the covariance matrices/likelihoods of the conditional modes are computed block-by-block.  We could certainly add functionality for this, but it isn't already there in the model somewhere to be extracted ...